# submit a code to microsoft-graph java-sdk

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks

I was trying to push to a new branch and submit a pull-request to

> msgraph-sdk-java

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java

in order to add some improvement but I am getting 403..
How to submit a code to Microsoft Graph Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Github, you [create a fork of the original repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-forks), make your changes and then [create a pull request from your fork](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork) to the original repository.

You are generally not allowed to create new branches on repositories you are not maintaining yourself.